# Why is this question called opinion-based?

Tags: discussion

This question: [When did it become a norm for mathematicians not to read proofs of all the results they use?](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/13136/14400)

I would expect answers to include evidence like "Mathematician X wrote that he had not read proofs". However, it was considered opinion-based and was closed. I don't know why.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my take on your [linked question](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/13136/14400).

It is impossible to answer it by anything other than an opinion, this is why it was closed.

1. **The current situation.** Note that your question is based on quotes from two anonymous sources. How can you be so sure that what's described by these sources represents *the current norm*? Keep in mind that there are tens of thousands of currently active mathematicians who live in different countries and work in different areas of math.

I have read many math papers and books, I have never came across a statement of the form "I never understood this proof in [X], but I will use this theorem anyway." There are two types of notable exceptions to this (which are widely understood as exceptions):

a. Instances when mathematicians use results where full proofs are not yet available. (I know of two examples: One is in the theory of finite groups and one is in the low-dimensional topology.)

b. Instances when mathematicians use results where the only available proofs are computer-aided. In this case, it is not even clear what does it mean to "read and understand the proof," regarding the computer-aided part. As far as I know, the first such proof is of the 4-color problem, in the mid 1970s.

In these instances, more careful writers might acknowledge this situation, but that's it.

Assuming that my personal experience is a reasonably representative sample, the only way to find out what  the current norm is, is  to undertake some massive opinion poll of currently active mathematicians. As far as I know, nobody tried to do this and it is very unlikely that anybody will do this in the foreseeable future.

2. **The situation in the past.** How are we supposed to find out what proofs mathematicians have read in the "old days"? (Not counting proofs in the first few books of Euclid that *everybody* was supposed to have mastered.)

Repeating myself: I have never read a paper written before 1960s from which I could infer that the author(s) did not read  proof(s) of theorem(s) that they use. In some cases, I can conclude that this did not happen since everything in a paper was proven from scratch, apart from usage of basic algebra/arithmetic, analysis/calculus and elementary geometry. (For instance, Poincare's papers are like that. For the record: Poincare's papers are the only original math papers written in the 19th century that I have read to some extent.) How representative is this (not using any older results by other mathematicians)? Answering by anything other than an opinion, would again require a massive effort, reading a variety of old (say, 19th century) papers, frequently written by obscure mathematicians using obscure terminology, etc. Nobody in their right mind is going to make such an effort.

Comment: Does this mean that questions that require a massive effort are considered "opinion-based", even though answers based on the opinion are not acceptable?

Comment: @PONPON: No. What I mean is: "A question is inappropriate for this site if its answers have to be either opinion-based or require massive efforts, far beyond what's feasible at SE."

Comment: I didn't know that. I think it is better not to close interesting but "big" questions.

Comment: Keep in mind that this is just my take, others may have different opinions.

Comment: Regarding the version of your post on math.stackexchange, here is a direct quote from [the tour of math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour): "Don't ask about... Questions with too many possible answers or that would require an extremely long answer."